# Parsing URL for scraping tasks

Tags: python, url, urllib

I want to parse Some URL and visit the site and further scrap some data.

Basically my current code is :

```py
i = 9
while(i < 118):
  dict = {'start': i}
  url1 = urllib.urlencode(dict)
  url2 = urlparse.urljoin('http://intelligencesquaredus.org/debates/past-debates ', url1)
  print url2
  i = i + 9
```

Which yields results

```
http://intelligencesquaredus.org/debates/past-debates/start=9
http://intelligencesquaredus.org/debates/past-debates/start=18
http://intelligencesquaredus.org/debates/past-debates/start=27
```

But i want the link to be

http://intelligencesquaredus.org/debates/past-debates?start=9

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want? You have a while loop that's the reason you have a result with many links.

Comment: results with many links is fine, that is intended behaviour.I just need the format to be correct.Please check again.

Comment: ok you want the `?` instead of `/`?

Comment: yes , now you are correct

Comment: ok. use `url2=('?'.join(('http://intelligencesquaredus.org/debates/past-debates '+url1).split(' ')))`. I think that will do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot man..That just fixed it :)

Comment: ok. Shall post it as an answer.

Comment: I recommend to use a list expression:
`base_url = "http://intelligencesquaredus.org/debates/past-debates"` and `[''.join((base_url, '?', 'start=', str(i))) for i in range(9, 118, 9)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use** :

```
url2=('?'.join(('http://intelligencesquaredus.org/debates/past-debates '+url1).split(' ')))
```

In the above snippet, your are taking the url as a string and adding the required string to it(`url1`).

Then you split by space to get a list with two elements which you later join with `?`.

**Alternative** (suggested by deloz) :

```
base_url = "http://intelligencesquaredus.org/debates/past-debates"
for a in([''.join((base_url, '?', 'start=', str(i))) for i in range(9, 118, 9)]):
    print(a)
```

Comment: That's using list comprehension.